# Implies sign between two lines

Tags: math-mode

I would like to achieve the below effect:

[image]

I was able to achieve something little bit similar with the following code, however it is a wrong solution.

```
\begin{ceqn}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
x_{1}=h \\
x_{2}=\dot{h} \\
\downarrow \\
\dot{x_{1}} = x_{2}\\
\dot{x_{2}} = u
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}
\end{ceqn}
```

My wrong solution:

[image]

Could you please let me know how to achieve the desired effect?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Notice that `\dot{x_{1}}` is different than `\dot{x}_{1}`. You probably want to use the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
x_1&=p\\
x_2&=\dot{p}
\end{aligned}
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}_1&=x_2\\
\dot{x}_2&=u
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple version (you might need to adjust spacing):

[image: implication]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{gathered}
x = y\\
y = x
\end{gathered} \Rightarrow \begin{gathered}
x = y\\
y = x
\end{gathered}
\]
\end{document}
```